# After my 4 month absence, why does my cat only recognize my flatmate as the owner?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

Here is an upsetting situation. I was away from home for 4 months because of work. My flatmate took care of my cat when I was away. Now I come back and find my cat run away from me. It has been 4 days since I came back. It seems he only recognizes my flatmate as his owner now that he purring when flatmate approching. We used to be very close and I have been taking care of him for 3 years. It is heartbreaking to see this situation, although I can understand.

I'm wondering if he would recognize me again as the owner since I start to feed him again? How can I make it up? How long it will take? Thank you very much.